# Programmr More User Input of Data

Tags: java

I was working on a challenge on Programmr and I found that my code wasn't passing the tests for the above named challenge even though when I compile and run the code with their online compiler, it gives me the desired output. Here's my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class Challenge{
      public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter the following information so I can sell it for a profit!:");

      System.out.print("First name: ");
      String fn = scanner.next();
      System.out.print("Last name: ");
      String ln = scanner.next();
      System.out.print("Grade (9-12): ");
      int grade = scanner.nextInt();
      while(grade < 9 || grade > 12) {
         System.out.println("Invalid Grade");
         System.out.println("Grade (9-12): ");
         grade = scanner.nextInt();
     }
     System.out.print("Student ID: ");
     String id = scanner.next();
     System.out.print("Login: ");
     String login = scanner.next();
     System.out.print("GPA (0.0-4.0): ");
     double gpa = scanner.nextDouble();

      while (gpa < 0 || gpa > 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid GPA");
        System.out.println("GPA (0.0-4.0): ");
        gpa = scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    ///{write you code here

    System.out.println("Login:"+ login); 
    System.out.println("ID:"+ id);
    System.out.println("Name:"+ ln +"; " + fn);
    System.out.println("GPA:"+ gpa);
    System.out.println("Grade:"+ grade);

///}

}

}
```

I wrote my code where the Challenge says `///{write you code here ///}` and it compiles and runs on their compiler but when I try submitting it, it says:

Our Input :
Amr Korayyem 12 11 Amr 4.23

Expected Output :
Amr
11
Korayyem; Amr
4.23
12

Your code's output:
29)

Pls, can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Give the link of challenge. Their input for GPA (i.e. 4.23) is out of range (i.e. > 4). Expected o/p should have been Invalid GPA.

Comment: Are you supposed to have the prompts, additional outputs and so forth? Have you tried to debug it any?

Comment: GPA (0.0-4.0): 4.23
Invalid GPA

Answer (score 0):

I've tried executing your code. Seems 4.23 is not a valid GPA according to your code.

Comment: The system is testing your code using 4.23 as gpa. Remove this constraint. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled and ran your code, everything works completely fine, although 4.23 is not a valid GPA.

```
 while (gpa < 0 || gpa > 4) {
    System.out.println("Invalid GPA");
    System.out.println("GPA (0.0-4.0): ");
    gpa = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

This line tells the code that if GPA is not between 0.0 and 4.0 to execute:

```
    System.out.println("Invalid GPA");
System.out.println("GPA (0.0-4.0): ");
```

Therefore you should not of got an output, and your program should just be stuck there. Try actually compiling your programs through the console/ terminal and running them. Otherwise if entered GPA is between 0.0-4.0 everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was offline for a while. I've tried your suggestions, I tried removing the 
        while (gpa < 0 || gpa > 4) {
            System.out.println("Invalid GPA");
            System.out.println("GPA (0.0-4.0): ");
            gpa = scanner.nextDouble();
        } 
and it now works. Thanks.